# Binary Search Tree Insertion using Recursion

Tags: recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

What am I doing wrong in the logic of the  below code : 
it is returning just the value of inserted node ,  not the whole tree. (See Output)

The method of printing the nodes of tree using the root node is predefined.I just have to return the root of the tree here.

```
 /* Node is defined as :
 class Node 
 int data;
 Node left;
 Node right;

 */

static Node Insert(Node root,int value)
 {       
  if(root == null){
     root = new Node();
     root.data= value ;
     return root;   
  }

 else{
  if(value<root.data)
   return Insert(root.left,value);

 else if(value > root.data)
     return  Insert(root.right,value);

 else return null;    
    }

   }
```

Input -

```
   5           //number of nodes

  4 2 3 1 7    // values of nodes

   6           //value of node to be inserted
```

(Expected)Output :

```
1 2 3 4 6 7
```

My output :

```
 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify if condition as:

```
if(root == null)
{
 root = new Node();
 root.data= value ;
 root.left=null;
 root.right=null;
 return root;
}
```

And modify the else condition as:

```
else
{
  if(value<root.data)
   {
     root.left=Insert(root.left,value);
     return root;
   }
  else if(value > root.data)
   {
     root.right= Insert(root.right,value);
     return root;
   }
  else 
   {
     System.out.println("duplicate value"); 
     return root;
   }
}
```